# display title and count how many times the title is in the database

Tags: php, mysql, count

sorry about my english.

Ok, so what i want to do is make a table like this:

```
nr | title  
2  | boop  
4 | beep  
1 | apples
```

the # row displays how many times the title on its right is in the table.

there are two tables: probleem (where a thema_id is placed every record), thema (where the theme title and id's are defined).

i've got the following code:

```
$themagetal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM probleem INNER JOIN thema ON probleem.thema_id = thema.thema_id ORDER BY probleem_id ASC");

while($vet = mysql_fetch_array($themagetal)){
    echo $vet['thema_id'] . ' ' . $vet['thema_tekst'] . '<br/>';
}
```

So i've read somewhere that i can use a count() to count the records. The problem is that i don't know how to use the count() without putting a mysql query in the while loop. i know that that's not really acceptable. how do i make that work?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp try this example

Comment: Please stop using PHP's long-since deprecated mysql_ API. See PDO/mysqli_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT b.title, count( b.title )
FROM probleem a, thema b
WHERE a.thema_id = b.thema_id
GROUP BY b.thema_id
```

It will results title and its count.

Comment: combining this with a while (fetch array) i managed to echo the title and the count of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql count:

```
    function getTitleCount(){       
      $themagetal = mysql_query(SELECT COUNT(probleem.probleem_id) AS title FROM probleem) ;
    $count = array('count' => 0);
    while($vet = mysql_fetch_array($themagetal)){
                    $count = array(
                        'count' => $vet['title'],
                    );
                }
   }
```

get the result as

```
$count = getTitleCount();    
$titleCount = $count['count'];
```

Comment: that only counts one value from the probleem table and doesnt return the title unfortunatly

Comment: it seems to return nothing, i tried echoing titleCount. double checked every name. no errormessage or anything

Comment: no need to apologise. i saw the $vet and $row mistake. still tho, nothing returns. i placed an echo in the while loop and saw that it echoed only once eventho there are 7 records. could it be that the mysql_fetch_array should be changed to someting else?